# How to use buttonSelected in Roku Scenegraph application

Tags: roku, scenegraph

I am making a user entry using KeyBoard dialog. I have kept two buttons "OK" and "CANCEL". But on using `buttonSelected` it is calling both the button using observeField. Now, can anyone tell me how to use `buttonSelected` index for getting action while clicking on one button as OK and Cancel

```
sub init()
  m.top.backgroundURI = "pkg:/images/rsgde_bg_hd.jpg"

  example = m.top.findNode("instructLabel")

  examplerect = example.boundingRect()
  centerx = (1280 - examplerect.width) / 2
  centery = (720 - examplerect.height) / 2
  example.translation = [ centerx, centery ]

  m.top.setFocus(true)
end sub

sub showdialog()
  keyboarddialog = createObject("roSGNode", "KeyboardDialog")
  keyboarddialog.backgroundUri = "pkg:/images/rsgde_dlg_bg_hd.9.png"
  keyboarddialog.title = "Example Keyboard Dialog"

  keyboarddialog.buttons=["OK","CANCEL"]
  keyboarddialog.optionsDialog=true

  m.top.dialog = keyboarddialog
  print "hello"
 KeyboardDialog.observeField("buttonSelected","onKeyPress")
' KeyboardDialog.observeField("buttonSelected","onKeyPressCancel")
 print "world"
end sub




function onKeyPress()
    print "m.value:::>>"m.top.dialog.text
end Function
function onKeyPressCancel()

    print "Screen should close"
end Function

function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
  if press then
    if key = "OK"
      showdialog()

      return true
    end if

    end if


  return false
end function



]]>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, Create one function for the dialog box. Inside a dialog box write observe field it's used Like below Example: First Parameter is a **"Field name"** and Another Parameter is a **"Function name"**.

`m.top.dialog.observeField("buttonSelected","onVerifyURL")` .

Below Function is a point to observe field Second Parameter **"onVerifyURL"**.

```
sub onVerifyURL()

 if m.top.dialog.buttonSelected = 0

       print "ok button pressed" 'O is called first
       'function call for OK

 else if m.top.dialog.buttonSelected = 1  

       print "cancel button pressed" '1 is called second
       'm.top.dialog.visible = false  
       'm.top.dialog.close = true
       'function call for Cancel

 else
       print "nothing press" ' this is not required for code just write for an understanding

 end if

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what's inside `buttonSelected` on event ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use `m.top.dialog.buttonSelected` which will return index value.